# Inner values in Python nested dictionary changing for no clear reason

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to create a nested dictionary indexed by two columns in a Pandas dataframe, but the inner values change each time a new key is added to an inner dictionary.

My intention is to have a dictionary whose keys are the values in one dataframe column, and whose values are dictionaries with keys from another column, where the values of the inner dictionaries are from a third column. I start with a blank structure for the nested dictionary, iterate through the rows of the dataframe, and update the dictionary values accordingly.

(I will demonstrate what I mean and what I have tried with dummy values.)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'label': ['a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2'],
                   'concept': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'],
                   'value': [1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4, 0.8, 0.7]})
results = dict.fromkeys(df['b'].unique(), dict.fromkeys(df['a'].unique(), 0))

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    results[row['concept']][row['label']] = row['value']
```

What I *expect* to get is:

```py
{
  ‘b1’: {
    ‘a1’: 1.0,
    ‘a2’: 0.6
  },
  ‘b2’: {
    ‘a1’: 0.5,
    ‘a2’: 0.6,
  },
  ‘b3’: {
    ‘a1’: 0.2,
    ‘a2’: 0.8,
  },
  ‘b4’: {
    ‘a1’: 0.7,
    ‘a2’: 0.7
  }
}
```

But instead what happens is that each time the loop encounters a `b` value which already exists, it correctly adds a new inner `a` key to the dictionary with the correct value but changes the previously added values. So for the above example I get:

```py
{
  'b1': {
    'a1': 0.7,
    'a2': 0.7
  },
  ‘b2’: {
    ‘a1’: 0.7,
    ‘a2’: 0.7,
  },
  ‘b3’: {
    ‘a1’: 0.7,
    ‘a2’: 0.7,
  },
  ‘b4’: {
    ‘a1’: 0.7,
    ‘a2’: 0.7
  }
}
```

I'm sure I must be missing something really obvious but it is making me want to bang my head against the wall! Can anyone offer any insights? I've tried an alternative approach using a new dataframe with labels and concepts as columns and indices respectively, but it's just far too slow to populate each cell one by one compared to a nested dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try pivoting the table and then convert to dictionary.

```
df.pivot_table(index='label',columns='concept',values='value').to_dict()
```

Comment: D'oh, why didn't I think of pivoting?! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're only creating one dict as python doesn't make copies of it for you. Thus, you are referencing the same dict in all the value parts of the key-value pairs in results.

An alternative would be to initialize results as below and keep rest of the code same:

```
results = {x: dict.fromkeys(df['label'].unique(), 0) for x in dict.fromkeys(df['concept'].unique())}
```

This will give you the expected output.

Alternatively you can change the approach and use pivot table as mentioned by Mark:

```
df.pivot_table(index='label',columns='concept',values='value').to_dict()
```

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation - that makes sense!

Comment: I would be thanked if you upvote the answer, though accept the answer of Mark.

Comment: Done, though it's not showing because I don't have enough reputation yet sorry!